# Load hybrid iOS and Android mobile app from server

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and Cordova to build a mobile app which will go on the iOS and Android stores. I have done this many times, and I really hate the process of having to update the app (specifically with Apple).

Would it be safe to dynamically load all of my templates and controllers from my server when the app loads, potentially caching them or having a server call to check if there is a new version? Basically, I would have all images and styles saved locally to the phone, but load the templates and controller code on app load.

And, if it was ok to do programmatically, are there any rules against this in Apple or Android's terms of use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible and there are tools like [Cordova Hot Code Push](https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-hot-code-push) to help you accomplish it. As long as you don't use this to break other app store review rules or significantly change the purpose of your app it's fine with Apple.

Comment: Thank you! This looks perfect. Will save loads of time.

Comment: @EverettGlovier - Are you still using it in your app with latest versions of android 9 and iOS 13?